# sys_refcursor result not visible

Tags: plsql

I created a procedure which will give the resultset in a SYS_REFCURSOR.
But I don't see the result set in the output, not even the count of records.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_get_job_run_details_test (p_details OUT sys_refcursor) AS
  l_start_date TIMESTAMP;
  date1        TIMESTAMP;
  l_end_date   TIMESTAMP;
  l_count      INTEGER;
  p_start_date date;
  p_end_date   date;
BEGIN
  p_start_date := '11-JUN-2019';
  p_end_date   := '11-JUN-2019';

 select to_timestamp_tz(p_start_date || ' 00:00:00 EUROPE/PARIS', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZR')
    into l_start_date
    from dual;

    select to_timestamp_tz(p_end_date || ' 23:59:59 EUROPE/PARIS', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZR')
    into l_end_date
    from dual;

  select count(*)
    into l_count
    FROM all_scheduler_job_run_details
   WHERE job_name = 'RANDOM_JOB'
     and log_date >= l_start_date
     and log_date <= l_end_date
     ;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_count);
    OPEN p_details FOR
      SELECT owner, log_date, job_subname,
             status, error# as error, req_start_date, actual_start_date,
             run_duration, additional_info
        FROM all_scheduler_job_run_details
       WHERE log_date >= l_start_date
         AND log_date <= l_end_date
         AND job_name = 'RANDOM_JOB'
       ORDER BY log_date DESC;

END p_get_job_run_details_test;
```

I am expecting one row as an output.
If I do this separately

```
SELECT *--count(*) into l_count
        FROM all_scheduler_job_run_details
       WHERE log_date >= to_timestamp_tz('11-JUN-19' || ' 00:00:00 EUROPE/PARIS', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS TZR')
         AND log_date <= to_timestamp_tz('11-JUN-19' || ' 23:59:59 EUROPE/PARIS', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS TZR')
         AND job_name = 'RANDOM_JOB';
```

I can see the result : 1 row.

Comment: Usually a prefix of `p_` is used to indicate a parameter. Using it for a local variable (usually `l_`) is likely to cause confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Your `p_start_date` and `p_end_date` variables are of the wrong datatype.
I ran your code, with the following line added after the `to_timestamp_tz` calls:

```
dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') || '|' || to_char(l_end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

The result was these nonsense dates with incorrect century:

> 0019-06-11 00:00:00|0019-06-11 23:59:59

The problem is these lines:

```
  p_start_date date;
  p_end_date   date;
BEGIN
  p_start_date := '11-JUN-2019';
  p_end_date   := '11-JUN-2019';
```

The variables are defined as `DATE`, so when a text literal is assigned to them, Oracle implicitly converts the literals to dates by applying your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. This is most likely not doing what you expect.

A simple fix would be to use proper `DATE` literals or `TO_DATE` conversions here:

```
  p_start_date := DATE'2019-06-11';
  p_end_date   := DATE'2019-06-11';
-- or
  p_start_date := TO_DATE('11-JUN-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY');
  p_end_date   := TO_DATE('11-JUN-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

Note that you also will have a problem in the `to_timestamp_tz` calls because Oracle will now implicitly convert your `date` variables to `varchar2` in order to concatenate with `' 00:00:00 EUROPE/PARIS'`.
Again, this will be done using your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting, which is likely not what you expect.

Either use an explicit `TO_CHAR` conversion with date mask or make `p_start_date` and `p_end_date` proper `varchar2` variables from the start.

Here's a version that works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_get_job_run_details_test (p_details OUT sys_refcursor) AS
  l_start_date TIMESTAMP;
  date1        TIMESTAMP;
  l_end_date   TIMESTAMP;
  l_count      INTEGER;
  p_start_date varchar2(20);
  p_end_date   varchar2(20);
BEGIN
  p_start_date := '11-JUN-2019';
  p_end_date   := '11-JUN-2019';

  select to_timestamp_tz(p_start_date || ' 00:00:00 EUROPE/PARIS', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZR')
    into l_start_date
    from dual;

    select to_timestamp_tz(p_end_date || ' 23:59:59 EUROPE/PARIS', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZR')
    into l_end_date
    from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') || '|' || to_char(l_end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));

  select count(*)
    into l_count
    FROM all_scheduler_job_run_details
   WHERE job_name = 'RANDOM_JOB'
     and log_date >= l_start_date
     and log_date <= l_end_date
     ;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_count);
    OPEN p_details FOR
      SELECT owner, log_date, job_subname,
             status, error# as error, req_start_date, actual_start_date,
             run_duration, additional_info
        FROM user_scheduler_job_run_details
       WHERE log_date >= l_start_date
         AND log_date <= l_end_date
         AND job_name = 'RANDOM_JOB'
       ORDER BY log_date DESC;

END p_get_job_run_details_test;
```

Comment: Hello Tad, thank you very much. the corrected code is working as expected. :)